# Azure log showing: "The supplied notification payload is invalid" for official Xamarin.Android sample

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services, pushsharp

So I tried running this Push notification sample for Xamarin.Android http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-android-get-started-push/ and after following instructions from the docs - I got it up and running. The insertion of items work absolutely fine however push notification refuses to work.

This is the error I get on Azure for push: Error: 400 - The supplied notification payload is invalid.

Anyone else tried running this sample on their device and tried push notifications? The error isn't doing much to help my case.

The sample is using PushSharp.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I send push notification to Google Cloud Messaging from the back-end server.

```c#
public async Task<bool> SendNotification(int id, int index, string from, string text, string tag)
{
    try
    {
        var payload = new
        {
            data = new
            {
                message = new
                {
                    // this part can be anything you want
                    id,
                    index,
                    from,
                    text,
                    when = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s") + "Z"
                }
            }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

        await _hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(json, tag);

        return true;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        // This is expected when an APNS registration doesn't exist.
        return false;
    }
```

Then in your app Intent Service, you can parse the JSON "message":

```c#
protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    var message = intent.Extras.GetString("message");

    // message is JSON payload
    // { "id":"someid", "index":"1", "text":"some text","from"... }

    var json = JObject.Parse(message);
    var id = json["id"].ToString();
    var index = json["index"].ToString();
    var text = json["text"].ToString();
    var from = json["from"].ToString();
    var when = DateTime.Parse(json["when"].ToString());

    // do whatever you want with your values here

}
```

Comment: Hey, backend IS azure - see the sample I linked above. I did manage to solve this and get Push notification success log however OnMessage method is never invoked. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you registered your device on startup?

Comment: Yep, logs shows that device is registered. Server says push was sent - however Onmessage() is never invoked.